# Java regex 2 ignore pattern between 2 words and should say match in if conditio

Tags: java

I have to find out the match between from and `IN_TXT` and anything between 2 words should be ignored and say it is matched.I tried with below expression but not working.,

```
String table="IN_TXT";
String s="select * from JAN_X.IN_TXT";
if((s.matches("from"+"(.*)"+table))){
   System.out.println``("Matched");
}
```

What might be missing here?

Comment: Try   `s.matches("^(.*)from" + "(.*)" + table )`   to match the stuff before the "from".

Comment: Thanks @DavidChoweller It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches` will add a `^` and `$` anchor so your regex is not completely matching against your input

so you can use `.*?` as `.*?from"+"(.*)"+table` where `.*?` will cover the string occurred before `from`

`.*?` match as few times as possible

```
String s = "select * from JAN_X.IN_TXT";
String table = "IN_TXT";
if ((s.matches(".*?from" + "(.*)" + table))) {
    System.out.println("Matched");
}
```

---

if you want to extract  `JAN_X` then you can use

```
    // $1 represents  (.*) capture group
    String s2= s.replaceAll(".*?from (.*)\\."+table,"$1");
    System.out.println(s2);
```

output

```
JAN_X
```

Comment: @bob87 i  am glad that i could help , happy coding

Comment: if the scenario is like below it is not working   it should not return but still it is matched.   String table="IN_TXT";
String s="select * from JAN_X.IN_TXT_A";
if((s.matches("from"+"(.*)"+table))){sysout("Matched")}

Comment: it's unclear , the above code didn't match but i guess you wants a match so seems like you want this `s.matches(".*from" + "(.*)" + table+"\w*")`

Comment: The secnario is like below. If the String table="IN_TXT"; String s="select * from JAN_X.IN_TXT where JAX_C=12" then it should be matched. 2) if String table="IN_TXT"; String s="select * from JAN_X.IN_TXT_A where JAX_C=12" then it shouldnt match(NoMATCH) 3) if String table="IN_TXT"; String s="select * from JAN_X.IN_TXT(TABLE_X,TAB_Y)"  then it should match. Only for the second scenario it shouldnt match as it contains table name as IN_TXT_A, if there is a underscore after the actual table name(i.e.,) IN_TXT then that should be not matched.

Comment: For the 3rd condition it should match eventhough there is no space between table name and open bracet(i.e., IN_TXT(.....)

Comment: for now you can use `s3.matches(".*?from" + "(.*)" + table+"([^_]).*` but what about something like `IN_TXT#$_A ` or `IN_TXTsas_` you have to come up with all possible cases otherwise it not recommended to keep on updating new requirements in old post though you are very welcome to post new question if you couldn't find any similar helpful  post

Comment: Thanks Pavneet. Sure.